# Integrating 3D Secure into Payius payment system

Tags: payment, 3d-secure

Is there anyone familiar with Payius payment system?

I have integrated the system in one website and now I have to add 3DS step. The only documentation I found (http://payius.com/media/pdf/Payius-Merchant-Integration-Giude.pdf) 
says I need to redirect the user to url `https:///merchant/mpi` which will perform a get request to the referrer as a callback. Now as I understand for testing purposes the url should be https://testpayments.payius.com/merchant/mpi right? In any case both bring up en error.

Did I get the documentation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the correct url for testing is `https://testpayments.payius.com/merchant/mpi`. It appears the mistake was in passed parameters. If you do not pass needed request parameters, the page will not be loaded at all.